# How to use IF statement in sqlcmd

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

If there is an error while running the procedure then echo 'error' else 'success'

```
sqlcmd -S DANAA-LAPTOP -d NewsWebsite -q "SP_DictionaryMain 'NewsWebsite','NEW'"  
       -o C:\logFile\ReportExE-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.txt
```

Comment: Write a script with the statements and pass it to `sqlcmd` instead of trying to stuff everything in the query parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try cmd `&&` and  `||` operators, where `&&` means previous command succesful and `||` means previous command failed.

as in

```
mycommand && echo success || echo error
```

you may also write compound commands within parens

```
mycommand && (set "somevar=ok" & echo success) || (set "somevar=ko" & echo error)
```

or, if you are running a batch script

```
mycommand && (
  set "somevar=ok" 
  echo success
) || (
  set "somevar=ko" 
  echo error
)
```

> Also, you need to use the `-b` switch to force `sqlcmd` return an
>   `ERRORLEVEL` that may be captured within batch or command line. This switch also forces `sqlcmd` to close when an error occurs.

so, in your case

```
sqlcmd -b -S DANAA-LAPTOP -d NewsWebsite -q "SP_DictionaryMain 'NewsWebsite','NEW'"  -o C:\logFile\ReportExE-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.txt 2>NUL && echo success || echo error
```

As you want to `echo` something, error output is suppressed with `2>NUL`. Remove it to see error messages from `sqlcmd`